Image overflowing grid's height
I'm trying to create a two-column layout with an image on the left and text content on the right using CSS grid. This looks fine on Firefox, but on Chrome the image keeps overflowing.
I've been trying to fix it but I've only been able by using absolute values which... doesn't seem right.

I'm just learning about web dev and honestly I just wish to understand why this happend and How can I prevent such a thing from happenning when using css grid


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  height: 3.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

header>* {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

span {
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 70vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%
}
<div class="hero">
  <article>
    <h1>Access a library of free design resources</h1>
    <p>The best resources and books from around the web, collected and curated for your reading.</p>
    <a href="">Get Access Now</a>
  </article>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
</div>




Its copy pasted from the code that caused the issue I just double checked. Does it display correctly on you screen? What browser are you using?

Firefox, but yes I can verify this happens on Chrome

How do you think would be the best way to fix such a problem? I was reading about normalizing css or straight up reseting it but I'm not sure about it

Set the grid row to the same height as the height of your grid-container and the image will not overflow.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%
}
<div class="hero">
  <article>
    <h1>Access a library of free design resources</h1>
    <p>The best resources and books from around the web, collected and curated for your reading.</p>
    <a href="">Get Access Now</a>
  </article>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
</div>




But now it doesn't cover. Setting max-height to 70vh explicitly (and keeping width 100%) seems to work - I don't claim to know why!

Fair but the image will either be clipped or distorted. Depends on what the OP wants.

Just add min-height: 0 or overflow: hidden to image to shrink it.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  height: 3.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

header>* {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

span {
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 70vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="hero">
  <article>
    <h1>Access a library of free design resources</h1>
    <p>The best resources and books from around the web, collected and curated for your reading.</p>
    <a href="">Get Access Now</a>
  </article>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
</div>



P.S. Related answer about width and flex: Why don't flex items shrink past content size?

I don't have a proper explanation for why the max-height: 100% doesn't work, but one workaround which gives cover as required is to explicitly set the height of the img element to 70vh.
That way the object-fit seems to know better what the dimensions of the item are and it implements the cover correctly.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}
<div class="hero">
  <article>
    <h1>Access a library of free design resources</h1>
    <p>The best resources and books from around the web, collected and curated for your reading.</p>
    <a href="">Get Access Now</a>
  </article>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">
</div>



